# change color of selected slice in Pie chart using iOS Charts

Tags: ios, ios-charts

In the iOS Charts library, unlike the `BarChartDataSet` class, the `PieChartDataSet` does not contain any property `highlightAlpha` that can be used to set a different alpha to the selected slice on the pie chart.

Although such a property can be introduced and using `CGContextSetAlpha()` we can modify the transparency of the highlighted slice, I want to do it without making any change in the library code. How can it be done?

Answer (score 0):

I checked the code, currently, it does not support this.

```
public override func drawHighlighted(context context: CGContext, indices: [ChartHighlight])
{
    ...
    CGContextSetFillColorWithColor(context, set.colorAt(xIndex).CGColor)
    ...
}
```

This just read data set color and use it to highlight. I think you are welcome to file a PR for such feature. Or I will do it when I have time.

For you, changing the source code seems the only option right now. That's why I think it's good for you to contribute.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. For now, I have implemented a solution in the delegate method. i have added that as an answer.

Answer (score 0):

For now, I have solved the problem using the delegate method:

```
- (void)chartValueSelected:(ChartViewBase * __nonnull)chartView
                     entry:(ChartDataEntry * __nonnull)entry
              dataSetIndex:(NSInteger)dataSetIndex
                 highlight:(ChartHighlight * __nonnull)highlight
{
    PieChartView *pPieChartView = (PieChartView *)chartView;

    PieChartDataSet *pDataSet = (PieChartDataSet *)[pPieChartView.data.dataSets objectAtIndex:dataSetIndex];

    NSMutableArray *pColors = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithArray:pDataSet.colors
                                                          copyItems:YES];

    for (int nIndex = 0; nIndex < pColors.count; nIndex++) {

        UIColor *pColor = [pColors objectAtIndex:nIndex];

        if (nIndex == entry.xIndex) {

            pColor = [pColor colorWithAlphaComponent:1];
        }
        else {

            pColor = [pColor colorWithAlphaComponent:0.3];
        }

        [pColors replaceObjectAtIndex:nIndex
                           withObject:pColor];
    }

    pDataSet.colors = pColors;
}
```

In my case, I load the slices with alpha component less than 1. On highlighting the slice, the alpha value is changed to 1.

The same effect can be achieved if the `highlightAlpha` property is introduced in `PieChartDataSet` class. In the `drawHighlighted` method, `CGContextSetAlpha(context, highlightAlpha)` needs to be called. The `BarChartDataSet` has highlight colors as well, which are absent in `PieChartDataSet`.